# Obfuscate Winform and its external dependencies (dlls)

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, obfuscation

I have a .NET winform which calls several methods from an external .NET DLL.  I obfuscated the winform no issue.  But when I obfuscated the DLL, my Winform doesn't run anymore.

Any idea how to protect the winform and the external DLL from reflector?

Thanks!

Comment: "But when I obfuscated the DLL, my Winform doesn't run anymore."  I think you'll need to be more specific if anyone is going to be able to help.

Comment: Sounds like an obfuscator error. Which one are you using? The whole point of using an obfuscator is to futz with the code but leave all functionality in place. Hmm. Maybe your DLL's public methods got obfuscated too and that's why your client/form code can no longer call/find them? Is there a setting or attribute you need to include on those methods so your obfuscator ignores them?

Comment: Pretty effective obfuscator, nobody is going to decompile *that*.  Get support from the vendor.

Comment: I still need to support environment with .NET v1.1 - so it's dotfuscator that shipped with VS 2003.  I think you're correct that after obfuscating the DLL the class/method name is no longer what I call in the winform.  This DLL is from other group and share with other projects.  My winform is the GUI for a specific customer.

Comment: You're not doing something weird like accessing the DLL using Reflection, right?

Comment: Nope - from my winform project, I add reference to the DLL; add using namespace of that DLL; call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've obfuscated both the winforms app and the DLL, I assume that means you have access to the source code for both.  If so, try incorporating the DLL into your winforms app as code (rather than as a DLL reference) and then obfuscating the whole thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't have the source code of the DLL because it's a shared DLL with other projects.  From Dotfuscator, i just point to this DLL and build it.  Did it twice: one for my winform and another one for the DLL.